# Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric error with MAX

Tags: sql-server

```
  SELECT x.Key, x.ID,
  MAX(CAST(CASE WHEN x.Display IS NULL THEN 0
  WHEN x.Display = 'Class' THEN 0
 WHEN x.Display = 'pricing' THEN 0
 WHEN x.Display = 1912.995 THEN 1913
 ELSE x.Display END as float)) AS GLwritten
 FROM x
 inner join y on y.rk_pk = x.pk
 group by x.Key, x.ID
```

If I didn't put WHEN x.Display = 1912.995 THEN 1913, then I get the following error:
 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1912.995' to data type int.

x.Display is nvarchar. 
I have no control over the design on the column unfortunately.

The error is Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1912.995' to data type int.

Comment: That's because you are storing numbers and strings in the same column. You would have to change this to ...when x.Display = '1912.995' then...And you really should consider redesigning things here.

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2010** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 - take your pick...

Answer (score 0):

You should really avoid storing mixed data types in the same column.

That said, I'm assuming your other values for `x.Display` are convertable to FLOAT.  You need to use the same datatype in each part of the CASE statement, then the CAST will work.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (Display NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @x (Display) VALUES ('Class');
INSERT @x (Display) VALUES ('pricing');
INSERT @x (Display) VALUES ('1912.995');
INSERT @x (Display) VALUES ('123.456');

SELECT
    MAX(
        CAST(
            CASE WHEN x.Display IS NULL THEN '0'
            WHEN x.Display = 'Class' THEN '0'
            WHEN x.Display = 'pricing' THEN '0'
            ELSE x.Display END
        AS FLOAT)
    ) AS GLwritten
FROM @x x
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `CASE` expression is the type of the value with the highest precedence. In this case the values are `0`, `0`, `0`, `1983`, and `Display`.  These are of types `int`, `int`, `int`, `int` and `nvarchar`.  Since `int` has higher precedence than `nvarchar`, the type of the `CASE` expression is `int`. And so it fails when you try to convert a value with a decimal point to `int`.

Note that `float` has higher precedence than `int`.  So if you can make one of the values to be type `float`, then the value of the whole `CASE` expression will be `float`.

One way to do this is to replace the first `0` with `cast(0 as float)`, the value of the `CASE` would be `float`, and the string conversion would work.

```
create table x ( Display nvarchar(20)     );

insert into x ( Display ) values
( NULL         ),
( 'Class'      ),
( 'pricing'    ),
( '1912.995'   ),
( '3.14159265' ),
( '2000'       )

  SELECT CASE WHEN x.Display IS NULL THEN 0
  WHEN x.Display = 'Class' THEN cast ( 0 as float ) -- <<<===
 WHEN x.Display = 'pricing' THEN 0
 WHEN x.Display = 1912.995 THEN 1913
 ELSE x.Display END AS GLwritten
 FROM x
```

Comment: Did you find this helpful?